# 4d np.array() acting like a 1d np.array()

Tags: python, numpy

Okay so this is a pretty long question. Here's the problem:

**Problem:** So I'm transfering images (3d arrays) into a numpy array. I'm trying to get a 4d array containing all of my images but for some reason, it prints out a 1d np.array containing 3d np.arrays.

**Suggested solutions**: 
- Images have different dimentions. This was the case but didn't help when resizing them.

First I'm transfering the each picture:
`cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8), -1)` converts my images from byte code to a 3d np array.

```
def transferPictures():
    x_dataset = []
    y_dataset = []
    x_decoded = []
    shoeNames = os.listdir(SHOES_DIRECTORY)
    print(len(shoeNames))
    for shoes in shoeNames[:20]:
        shoeDirectoriesPath = os.path.join(SHOES_DIRECTORY, shoes)
        if(os.path.isdir(shoeDirectoriesPath)):
            eachPicture = os.listdir(shoeDirectoriesPath)
            for pic in eachPicture:
                print(pic)
                picPath = os.path.join(shoeDirectoriesPath, pic)
                f = open(picPath, 'rb')
                image_bytes = f.read()
                #This is to convert the image from byte format to a 3d np array:
                decoded = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8), -1) 
                x_dataset.append(decoded) 
                y_dataset.append(pic)
    return [x_dataset, y_dataset]
```

And converting my x_dataset list (containing all my images) to an np.array():

```
dataset = transferPictures()
x_dataset=np.array(dataset[0])
```

I get a 1d x_dataset np.array containing 3d np.arrays:

```
print("This is the type of the array of images, x_dataset: "+ str(type(x_dataset)))
print("This is the type of each image, x_dataset[0]: "+ str(type(x_dataset[0])))

print("This is the dimension of the array of images, x_dataset: "+ str(np.shape(x_dataset)))
print("This is the dimension of each image, x_dataset[0]: "+ str(np.shape(x_dataset[0])))
```

Prints:

```
This is the type of the array of images, x_dataset: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
This is the type of each image, x_dataset[0]: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
This is the dimension of the array of images, x_dataset: (130,)
This is the dimension of each image, x_dataset[0]: (289, 200, 3)
```

Why does the `np.shape(x_dataset)` return (130,) and the `np.shape(x_dataset[0])` return (289, 200, 3)?

1) Shouldn't the `np.shape(x_dataset)` return (130, 289, 200, 3)?

2) How can I get a 4d x_dataset with shape (130, 289, 200, 3)?

**EDIT:**

V. Ayrat suggested it might be because of the difference in shape of each image. Some images were in fact of different dimensions that others. So I resized all images to have the same shape. But, the problem seems to persist:

Finding the dimensions of the smallest image:

```
minx = 1000
miny = 1000
minz = 1000


for image in x_dataset:
    if np.shape(image)[0] < minx:
        minx = np.shape(image)[0]
    if np.shape(image)[1] < miny:
        miny = np.shape(image)[1]
    if np.shape(image)[2] < minz:
        minz = np.shape(image)[2]

print(minx)
print(miny)
print(minz)
```

Prints:

```
288
200
3
```

Resizing images:

```
for i in range(0,len(x_dataset)):
    x_dataset[i] = np.resize(x_dataset[i], (minx,miny,minz))
```

The images have all the same dimensions but checking for the dimension `x_dataset` still returns (130,). Any other ideas to have it return a 4d array?

**EDIT 2:**
Making 100% sure each image is of the same dimension:

```
minx = 1000
miny = 1000
minz = 1000
maxx = 0
maxy = 0
maxz = 0

for image in x_dataset:
    if np.shape(image)[0] < minx:
        minx = np.shape(image)[0]
    if np.shape(image)[1] < miny:
        miny = np.shape(image)[1]
    if np.shape(image)[2] < minz:
        minz = np.shape(image)[2]
    if np.shape(image)[0] > maxx:
        maxx = np.shape(image)[0]
    if np.shape(image)[1] > maxy:
        maxy = np.shape(image)[1]
    if np.shape(image)[2] > maxz:
        maxz = np.shape(image)[2] 
print()    
print(minx)
print(miny)
print(minz)
print(maxx)
print(maxy)
print(maxz)
```

Prints:

```
288
200
3

288
200
3
```

And rechecking the type:

```
print(type(x_dataset))
print(type(x_dataset[0]))
print(np.shape(x_dataset))
```

Prints:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(130,)
```

This is really confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x_dataset` is python `list` object which store `nunpy.array` objects. If inner numpy arrays have different sizes `np.shape` return only length of list. So you can make it full numpy object only if all pictures have the same size which is not case I guess.

In order to check if your array of images, `x_dataset`, has images of different sizes, run:

```
minx = 10000
miny = 10000
minz = 10000
maxx = 0
maxy = 0
maxz = 0

for image in x_dataset:
    if np.shape(image)[0] < minx:
        minx = np.shape(image)[0]
    if np.shape(image)[1] < miny:
        miny = np.shape(image)[1]
    if np.shape(image)[2] < minz:
        minz = np.shape(image)[2]
    if np.shape(image)[0] > maxx:
        maxx = np.shape(image)[0]
    if np.shape(image)[1] > maxy:
        maxy = np.shape(image)[1]
    if np.shape(image)[2] > maxz:
        maxz = np.shape(image)[2] 

print(minx)
print(miny)
print(minz)
print(maxx)
print(maxy)
print(maxz)
```

Then if images are of different dimensions, resize them with:

```
for i in range(0,len(x_dataset)):
    x_dataset[i] = np.resize(x_dataset[i], (minx,miny,minz))
```

If the problem persists, change your arrays to a list and then back to an array as so:

```
x_dataset = np.array(x_dataset.tolist())
x_dataset = np.array(x_dataset)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer V. Ayrat. I followed your advice but there seems to be another problem as well. I added my progress in the question. Would you have any other ideas?

Comment: Try `x_dataset = np.array(x_dataset)`. If all sizes are the same `x_dataset.shape` should be (130, 288, 200, 3).

Comment: I am just not sure what is the type of `x_dataset` after all your changes if it is still `list` `x_dataset = np.array(x_dataset)` should work.

Comment: I just checked your suggestions but it doesn't seem to be the problem.... The checking is in the **Edit2** section

Comment: All this lists and arrays become very entangled)): can you try `x_dataset = np.array(x_dataset.tolist())`?

Comment: Yes! Converting it to a list and then back to a np.array worked!! Thank you!!!!